# Running Minecraft from a backup folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

I have several backups of my Minecraft folder, all inside my roaming folder, named (in order) `MinecraftOld1` `MinecraftOld2` and so on. However, you are unable to rename a folder to `.minecraft` (or `.anythinghere` for that matter too), so how can I replace my .minecraft folder with one of my backups? Copying/pasting is not an option owing to the size of the backups I make (it will take around an hour to move it into the new folder, and surely there must be a quicker way to just rename the folder?)

Any alternatives that allow me to run the game from this backup folder are also welcomed.

Comment: This is basic Windows techniques. This is in no way specific to any game.

Comment: @Frank However Minecraft and it's modded variants rely on naming files with a . in the beginning. If there's a way to run Minecraft with a different file path (that doesn't require usage of the .minecraft) then that will be a happy alternative to overcome the same problem.

Comment: That is not what you're asking, though. You're asking specifically how to rename things with a protected character. That's a Windows limitation, not a gaming one.

Comment: I have edited the question to accept other alternatives, however the preferred outcome is not to mess with the original naming of files within the the game.

Comment: Instead of copy and pasting, you can *cut* and paste. I'm fairly confident that's just a rename operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Command Prompt to rename folders and files with otherwise "illegal" characters.  It's a fairly simple process, though it may seem scary since it's the command prompt.

1. Open a Command Prompt (search "cmd" in the Windows Search bar)
2. Change to the directory that contains the folder you wish to rename.  To do this, you will need to use the `cd` command (change directory).  If you don't want to type out the full path of the folder, open a File Explorer, and navigate to the folder that contains the file/folder you wish to rename.  Then, type `cd` (with a space) into the command prompt instance, and then click and drag the folder from the File Explorer instance into the command prompt.  This will automatically put the path into the command prompt for you. Otherwise, type out the path exactly as it is.
3. Press enter.  Your current directory should now be changed.
4. Type `rename <"original folder name"> <"new folder name">` (don't include the `<` or `>`).  In this case, for your `<"new folder name">`, you will want `.minecraft`.  Note that the double quotes are only necessary if spaces are in the folder/file name.  You can omit them otherwise.
5. Press enter, and your folder should be renamed!

Here is a picture of my example doing this, as well as an [additional source](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000846.htm) that explains the above steps:

[image: My example]

Comment: You can also shift right-click in explorer and `Open command prompt here` or something along those lines. Also for faster access, `AppData/Roaming` is `%AppData%`

Answer (score 1):

You should change your launcher profile settings to use another game directory.

This is possible on the default launcher.

After opening the launcher, go to Launch options, and click on the slider for Advanced settings. Click on one of your launcher profiles and you should now see the option for Game directory (click on the slider to be able to edit it). You can edit the filepath used to launch minecraft from here. 
[image: game directory option]

Optionally, you could create another launcher profile for your "backup" directory and then follow the same steps

Answer (score -1):

With the new launcher this is a bit more difficult than previously.  You used to be able to create a 'bat' file to set your %Appdata% variable to any folder you wish and then launch Minecraft.

The easiest way to have multiple versions of MC and worlds is to use MultiMC which can be found [here.](https://multimc.org/)

Comment: Does MultiMC effect the way Minecraft runs in any way? Just a network on which I operate has a packet-based anti-cheat and if this messes with the way Minecraft sends packets I could be in trouble.

Comment: @Crafter0800 I am not sure.  I have used it to connect to external servers without any issues.

Comment: The default launcher profile feature can be used to have different versions and game directories (and therefore separate folders/files for saves, servers.dat, resourcepacks, mods, etc). I think that is far easier than downloading a whole new launcher.

Comment: @getfugu - If you play vanilla MC sure, but modded MC, especially if you play multiple versions, is much easier to set up and maintain in MultiMC.